# calculate final mark

Tags: linear-algebra

A uni course has a presentation that contributes 20% to the final mark of the course and a written test that contributes the rest 80%. If someone got 25 marks more (out of 100) to the presentation, how much he will get more in the final mark if we got the same mark in the written test? I reckon it is 5 marks out of 100, but some people say 1!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you got an $x$ for the presentation ($0\le x\le75$) and a $y$ for the test($0\le y\le100$). Then your friend will have
$$
\left(0.2\frac{x+25}{100} + 0.8\frac{y}{100}\right) - \left(0.2\frac{x}{100} + 0.8\frac{y}{100}\right) = 0.2*25 = 5
$$
higher.

Comment: this is 0.5 of a 100-scale higher? That's too low! Also, you say 0.2*25= 0.5 while it's 5!

Comment: Fixed it, it is indeed 5 on a scale of 100. In the Netherlands we always work on a scale of 1-10, so the answer was automatism^^